# Get coordinates from drawn items with Mapbox-gl-draw

Tags: coordinates, map-drawing, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using [mapbox-gl-draw](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw) in my application and I need to get and save the coordinates of the drawn items on the map. I've checked and I found [turf getCoor](http://turfjs.org/docs/#getcoord) method, but I don't know how to access the info because I'm using the default set of tools, which you obtain thru the lines below

```
var Draw = mapboxgl.Draw();

map.addControl(Draw);
```

Can someone help me figure this out? I'm sure it's pretty easy, I just can't find as many examples online as I wanted it.

**EDIT**

Also, while trying to figure this out I got type error from turf, which it means just calling `<script src='//api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/turf/v1.3.0/turf.min.js'></script>` in my html file didn't work. Am I including it wrong? with https: before the slashes didn't work either.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. Did you ever find your answer?

Comment: Did you solve? I've the same trouble ...

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `Draw.getAll()`.

It should return a feature collection containing all of the drawn features.

The reference for this is [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/blob/master/docs/API.md#getall-featurecollection).